# Lock icon with Autos variables in Visual studio. What does it denote?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, icons

[image: Lock symbols]

What does the *small lock icon* in `Auto` window denote in visual studio?

I often see them while debugging, but have no idea what they denote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window auto is referring to the current code line +- some lines (depending on the language used). 
It shows every variable accessible from that context.

The lock is indicating that the according variable is a protected member of a class. It can only be accessed by its own class or classes inherited from it.

e.G. the context you are currently observing has three protected members ( m_playbackAborted, m_recordingState and m_state).

Comment: typo maybe, "specified member" perhaps